# How to fix duplicate elements in local storage when I set them?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to set elements with information from an HTML tag to the localStorage. The idea is: the element already exists in localStorage?, if it does then push the new element, and set it again in the localStorage, but if it doesn't, then create the object, keep the element on it, and set it in the localStorage.

I already have the evaluations, and everything goes fine until the user clicks on an HTML element for the second time, because it starts duplicating the elements in localStorage. 
I show you some of my code:

```
$j('a.a-links').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!localStorage.getItem('Navegacion-Prueba')) {
        localStorage.setItem('Navegacion-Prueba', JSON.stringify([]));
        console.log('creates object in local storage');
    }
    var objectFromLS = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('Navegacion-Prueba')),
        focus = e.target,
        categoryL1 = $j(focus).parents('li.submenu-li-first').find('.submenu-li-link').html(),
        categoryL2 = $j(focus).parents('.subsubcater-ul-full').find('a').html(),
        // console.log(categoryL2);
        categoryL3 = $j(focus).html(),
        // console.log(categoryL3);
        cont = 1,
        navObjRed = {
            "CatN1": categoryL1,
            "CatN2": categoryL2,
            "CatN3": categoryL3,
            "Cont": cont
        };
        console.log(objectFromLS);
    if (objectFromLS.length === 0) {
        objectFromLS.push(navObjRed);
        // localStorage.setItem("Navegacion-Prueba", JSON.stringify(objectFromLS));
        console.log(objectFromLS);
        // return objectFromLS;
    } else {
        $j(objectFromLS).each(function (o) {
            if (o.CatN3 === categoryL3) {
                o.CatN3 += 1;
                // localStorage.setItem("Navegacion-Prueba", JSON.stringify(objectFromLS));
                console.log('object already exists, adding 1 to counter');
                // return objectFromLS;

            } else {
                objectFromLS.push(navObjRed);
                console.log('object already exists, adding a new object');
                // return objectFromLS;

            }
        })
    }
    localStorage.setItem("Navegacion-Prueba", JSON.stringify(objectFromLS));
    console.log('setting the object in local storage');
});
```

What I expect to happen is that every time user clicks an "a" tag, the information in the localStorage updates wether it's already set and the update consists on adding 1 to the counter, or just the clicked element isn't stored and it needs to be added to the existing object, or if it has to be created from the beginning. This already happens, but it duplicates every time the user clicks the elements.

This is what happens:
Nav_Red: [{CatN1: "Electrónica", CatN2: "Videojuegos", CatN3: "Nintendo Switch", Cont: 1},…]

0: {CatN1: "Electrónica", CatN2: "Videojuegos", CatN3: "Nintendo Switch", Cont: 1}

1: {CatN1: "Niños", CatN2: "Niño", CatN3: "Ropa", Cont: 1}

2: {CatN1: "Hogar", CatN2: "Muebles", CatN3: "Mesas", Cont: 1}

3: {CatN1: "Hogar", CatN2: "Muebles", CatN3: "Mesas", Cont: 1}

4: {CatN1: "Gourmet", CatN2: "Destilados y Licores", CatN3: "Mezcal", Cont: 1}

5: {CatN1: "Gourmet", CatN2: "Destilados y Licores", CatN3: "Mezcal", Cont: 1}

6: {CatN1: "Gourmet", CatN2: "Destilados y Licores", CatN3: "Mezcal", Cont: 1}

7: {CatN1: "Gourmet", CatN2: "Destilados y Licores", CatN3: "Mezcal", Cont: 1}

8: {CatN1: "Mujer", CatN2: "Ropa", CatN3: "Chamarras y Chalecos", Cont: 1}

9: {CatN1: "Mujer", CatN2: "Ropa", CatN3: "Chamarras y Chalecos", Cont: 1}

10: {CatN1: "Mujer", CatN2: "Ropa", CatN3: "Chamarras y Chalecos", Cont: 1}

11: {CatN1: "Mujer", CatN2: "Ropa", CatN3: "Chamarras y Chalecos", Cont: 1}

12: {CatN1: "Mujer", CatN2: "Ropa", CatN3: "Chamarras y Chalecos", Cont: 1}

13: {CatN1: "Mujer", CatN2: "Ropa", CatN3: "Chamarras y Chalecos", Cont: 1}

14: {CatN1: "Mujer", CatN2: "Ropa", CatN3: "Chamarras y Chalecos", Cont: 1}

15: {CatN1: "Mujer", CatN2: "Ropa", CatN3: "Chamarras y Chalecos", Cont: 1}

And so on... as many times the user clicks.

Comment: `if (!localStorage.getItem('Navegacion-Prueba') { localStorage.setItem('Navegacion-Prueba'); }`

Comment: I just changed that part, now I evaluate if the element is in the LS, and at the end I set the object in the LS, but it keeps duplicating the elements.
Do you have any other suggestion?

Comment: with my understanding, you always append the new item as soon as  `o.CatN3 === categoryL3` is false. try to find why is that. and can you provide what you expect. you are only checking CatN3 and not the other ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution to my problem, and I'll show you, I hope this is helpful to other people:

```
$j('a.a-links').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!localStorage.getItem('Navegacion-Prueba')) {
        localStorage.setItem('Navegacion-Prueba', JSON.stringify([]));
    }
    var objectFromLS = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('Navegacion-Prueba')),
        focus = e.target,
        categoryL1 = $j(focus).parents('li.submenu-li-first').find('.submenu-li-link').html(),
        categoryL2 = $j(focus).parents('.subsubcater-ul-full').find('a').html(),
        categoryL3 = $j(focus).html(),
        cont = 1,
        navObjRed = {
            "CatN1": categoryL1,
            "CatN2": categoryL2,
            "CatN3": categoryL3,
            "Cont": cont
        };
    if (Object.keys(objectFromLS).length === 0) {
        objectFromLS.push(navObjRed);
    } else if (Object.keys(objectFromLS).length !== 0) {
        var validator = false;
        localStorage.setItem('Navegacion-Prueba', JSON.stringify([]));
        $j(objectFromLS).each(function () {
            if (this.CatN3 === categoryL3) {
                this.Cont += 1;
                 validator = false;
            } else {
                validator = true;
            }
        })
        if (validator === true) {
            objectFromLS.push(navObjRed);
        } else {
            console.log('no adding new element');
        }
    }
    localStorage.setItem("Navegacion-Prueba", JSON.stringify(objectFromLS));
});
```

As you can see, the problem was that I was pushing the new element inside the loop, so it pushed it as many times as the number of elements inside the object in the localStorage. So I just push outside the loop.

Thanks to everyone to who answered to me!